# Is it possible to use two versions of SLF4J?

Tags: java, slf4j

I have two different dependencies that require two different SLF4J versions `1.5` and `1.7`.
Is there any way to make them work together?

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. You should not have two different versions of the same library on the classpath. If you are using Maven or Gradle to build this is usually taken care of, the tools will only resolve one version of the dependency and use that one.